# How do I query a secondary index on DynamoDB in Java

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am writing an app using which people can request information about specific events.  Because multiple users can request information about the same event, the key for my Request table is username+event (where both of those are strings).

However, in the Java code which supplies that information, I don't want to download data I don't need so, ideally, I'd query on the event (as I don't know the usernames of all the people making the query).

I thought that if I gave the Request table a secondary index, called "event", which the users also filled in (so the hash key (called "key") is username+event, and the event field is just the event string), I'd able to query on the secondary index, and get all the requests for that event.

Here's the code:

```
Map<String, Condition> keyConditions = new HashMap();
keyConditions.put("event", new Condition()
                    .withComparisonOperator(EQ)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(event)));
QueryRequest one = new QueryRequest()
    .withTableName(REQ_TABLE)
    .withIndexName("event")
    .withKeyConditions(keyConditions);
QueryResult queryResult = dynamoDB.query(one);
```

All I get, however, is this error message:
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Query condition missed key schema element: key

Removing the call to withIndexName("event") makes no difference.

I haven't used NoSQL before this week, which may be part of the problem.

Comment: can you also post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `"event"` is the name of the attribute that is indexed *and* the name of the index?

You are using it as the attribute name in the query:

```
keyConditions.put("event", new Condition()
                .withComparisonOperator(EQ)
                .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(event)));
```

And you're using it as the index name:

```
 .withIndexName("event")
```

In the DynamoDB console of your AWS dashboard, check the *Indexes* tab to see what the name of the index is. It's been a little while since I created an index but I believe by default AWS usually postfixes the index name with `_index`.

Comment: Thanks for the implied assistance; but I've decided to do it in what I suspect is the proper way: using event as the hash key, but having the user identifier as a primary sort key, and it works perfectly.